# Save information from one table into another using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I need to save a color code to my color_codes table but I also want to save the name of who saved it. I have a users_table with the information on it.

```
<?php
include("db_connect.php");

$color = $_POST['color'];
$colorName = $_POST['colorName'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO color_codes (color_code, color_name) VALUES ('" . $color . "', '" . $colorName . "')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

} else {

}
?>
```

Comment: Then query your users_table first to get user info and insert it in color_codes table.

Comment: how do you identify which user issued the post?  how is that identification tied to the user table?

Answer (score 0):

1) add another column as user_id in the 'color_codes' table.

2) get the current user id from the SESSION or from the users_table.

3) change your query to this

$sql = "INSERT INTO color_codes (color_code, color_name, user_id) VALUES ('" . $color . "', '" . $colorName . "', '" . $user_id . "')";